# Getting rid of phone number extension on Pandas DF

Tags: python, regex, pandas, indexing

I have a list of phone numbers that came in many different formats, but I need to extract the typical 10-digit format "area code + phone number".

I've successfully removed punctuation, but some pesky phone numbers have extensions on them. I thought I'd create a length column, then have some sort of condition to only remove the last 4 characters if the phone number length is greater than 10.

Below is a sample of what my data looks like. First phone number should not lose any digits; the second one should lose the "1401"

```
phone = pd.DataFrame({'PN':['1234567891', '1234567891 1401'],'length':[10,16]})
```

I've tried to replace these last four digits with re.sub, but I can't seem to get it right.

```
phone[phone['length']>10]= re.sub(r'\d{4}$', '', phone['PN'])
```

This doesn't work either:

```
phone[phone['length']>10,'PN']=phone.loc[phone['length']>10]['PN'].str.replace('\d{4}$', '')
```

I get an "'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed" error, but I don't know what it means or how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use slice as:

```
phone['PN'] = phone['PN'].str.slice(0, 10)
```

or,

`phone['PN'] = phone['PN'].str[:10]`

Comment: This worked! Both answers were "oh duh!" moments for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! `Happy Coding.`